# Datatables multiple select afnFiltering

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, variables, datatables

I have multiple select menus which are used to filter a table using jquery datatables.

The following code i use works brilliant, but for this example I am only using 3 select menus.
I now have a table which will be using upwards of 10.

Is there a better way of writing this so I don't have to write every variation of matches.

**//UPDATE**

If I put the select vars and the tabledata column vars in array can I iterate through them.

```
$.fn.dataTableExt.afnFiltering.push(
    function( oSettings, aData, iDataIndex ) {
          if ( oSettings.nTable == document.getElementById( 'logtable' ))
          {

          var nature_of_complaint = document.getElementById('nature_of_complaint_select').value;
          var division = document.getElementById('division_select').value;
          var resolved = document.getElementById('resolved_select').value;

          var tabledata_nature_of_complaint = aData[22];
          var tabledata_division = aData[12];
          var tabledata_resolved = aData[26];

          if (nature_of_complaint == "" && division == "" && resolved == "")
          {  return true;  }
          else if (tabledata_division == division && nature_of_complaint == "" && resolved == "")
          {  return true;  }
          else if (tabledata_nature_of_complaint == nature_of_complaint && division == "" && resolved == "")
          {  return true;  }
          else if (tabledata_resolved == resolved && division == "" && nature_of_complaint == "")
          {  return true;  }
          else if (tabledata_nature_of_complaint == nature_of_complaint && tabledata_division == division && resolved == "")
          {  return true;  }
          else if (tabledata_division == division && tabledata_resolved == resolved && nature_of_complaint == "")
          {  return true;  }
          else if (tabledata_resolved == resolved && tabledata_nature_of_complaint == nature_of_complaint && division == "")
          {  return true;  }
          else if (tabledata_nature_of_complaint == nature_of_complaint && tabledata_division == division && tabledata_resolved == resolved)
          {  return true;  }
          return false;
          } else
          return true;
    }
);
```

Comment: I gave up trying to understand the technical requirement... but one thing seems like it would be worth considering: test for the case, when you need to return `false`. Those seems to be less common. Also, first normalize conditions. I.e. if `!division` is equivalent to `division == tabledata_division`, then reduce it to the former - you'll have half the cases to test.

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out using this tutorial.

http://www.flynsarmy.com/2011/12/save-custom-filter-state-jquery-data-tables/

Just add class of 'dtable_filter' to each select.

Here is the reduced code:

```
$.fn.dataTableExt.afnFiltering = new Array();
    var oControls = $('#adv_search_filters').find(':input[name]');
    oControls.each(function() {
        var oControl = $(this);

        //Add custom filters
        $.fn.dataTableExt.afnFiltering.push(function( oSettings, aData, iDataIndex ) {
            if ( !oControl.val() || !oControl.hasClass('dtable_filter') ) return true;

            for ( i=0; i<aData.length; i++ )
                if ( aData[i].indexOf(oControl.val()) != -1 )
                    return true;

            return false;
        });
    });
```